# Modifying a quaternion while updating

Tags: unity-game-engine

I think like many beginners, I am struggling to grasp the application of quaternions, particularly how to manipulate them manually...

I have a mecanim model (that is essentially an array of poses) so every frame, I need to update my model with the latest pose, so it looks *live*.

I use 23 mecanim bones, so having mapped my model's bones onto Unity's mecanim system, I wanna treat the *head* differently, by making it turn in the opposite direction of what the motion data dictates, or whatever: something that shows the head moving differently.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {                       
        case (int)AnimationSegment.Head:
            model[i].rotation = pose[i].rotation;  // Let's turn the head...
            break;

        default:
            model[i].rotation = pose[i].rotation;
            break;
    }
}
```

What do I multiply `pose[i].rotation` by (the one on the comment line) in order to, for example, rotate the head 45 degrees more than how it would have been?

The following was my own unsuccessful attempt (which hopefully show how I have misunderstood quaternions, so I would appreciate any help):

```
Quaternion q = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-x, y, z));
```

After this, I changed that line with comment to:

```
model[i].rotation = pose[i].rotation * q;
```

Comment: You will need a void update method. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html. As for the actual code, I am also a beginner in Unity but try what you have previously done and implement it in a void update method as any code in update method updates per frame. If you want  the head opposite of the current direction, surely a simple multiply by -1 of the x and y rotation would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quaternions can be somewhat complicated, even after having used them I always have to go back to the documentation and look them up.  If you really want to understand all that stuff and how combining them works you can look up some stuff on linear algebra or...

**Avoid the Problem**

Use the .eulerAngles function of your existing quaternion to pull out the rotation around the x, y and z axis.  Then you can manipulate these however you want.  For example like you said about rotating something 45 degrees more

```
Vector3 existingAngles = model[i].rotation.eulerAngles;
Vector3 newAngles = new Vector3(existingAngles.x, existingAngles.y, existingAngles.z + 45);
model[i].rotation.eulerAngles = newAngles;
```

Just keep in mind that you can always convert from an often hard to work with 4x4 matrix (quaternion) to euler angles and back again, and I'd reccomend that you stick with manipulating the angles and reassigning for simple cases.